# Keeping distance between panels the same

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I have several panels in a windows form application, they are sorted in two columns and maximally 4 rows, so maximally 8 panels. The number of elements included in every single panel changes during the runtime, so not to waste place on monitor I set all of them to autosize. The problem is, I dont know how I can keep them placed correctly, like how to make that when the first one shrinks that the other three come up a bit so there is not too much space between them.

Comment: What control do you use now for placing panels in four rows and two columns? If first one panel shrinks - which panels should change their size - panels from current row, or from column?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the `TableLayoutPanel` or the `FlowLayoutPanel` (or possibly even a `SplitContainer`). They all can be very useful for this kind of task. You find them in the section `Containers` in the Toolbox. You can keep the right distance by setting the margins of the panels appropriately. The `TableLayoutPanel` gives you different options for sizing the rows and columns (absolute or percent size or auto). Also by working with the `Dock` or the `Anchor` properties of the panels and controls you can attain a dynamic behavior when resizing or adding and removing controls.

You might also have to set the `MinimumSize` and `MaximumSize` properties of the controls.

You can add controls like this the `TableLayoutPanel`

```
int count = tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count;
int newColumn = count % 2;
int newRow = count / 2;
if (newRow >= tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount) {
    tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount++;

    // Set appropriate row style
    tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle { SizeType = SizeType.AutoSize });
}
var newControl = new Button { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(newControl, newColumn, newRow);
```

Comment: @ lazyberezovsky: This is a visual thing, not so much a code thing. If the panels have the right width, they will wrap to the next row automatically after two columns in the `FlowLayoutPanel`.

Comment: Yes, it's not code thing, but saying that you can use TableLayoutPanel for controls positioning is like saying that you can use Linq to load customer data from database :)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky:  I addd an example for the `TableLayoutPanel`.