# how to auto adjust controls when their size changes c#

Tags: c#, dynamic, user-controls, runtime

I have on `winform` an `usercontrol` that can be multiple created dynamically at runtime. I have two ways to see them: in maximal mode and minimal mode. The idea is that ,when they are minimal,some objects from `usercontrol` are hidden. I want,if I switch to maximal mode,the usercontrols to be automatically adjusted .How can I do that?I started with the idea to compute their width and height ,but I don't know how to create the new points.  My pictures below show better:

this is in minimal mode:

[image]

how they look when I change it to maximal mode: [image]

how I would like to be usercontrols: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Dock` or `Anchor` property for this.

Eg. `groupBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Top;`

**MSDN For Dock:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock.aspx

**MSDN For Anchor:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx

**Article With Exaple:**

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/manage-winform-controls-using-the-anchor-and-dock-properties/6165908

Comment: but,if the distance between 2 usercontrol is for example 50,I would like,when they are maximal,this distance to  be kept.

Comment: @Mady dont go on as it is, but just refer how this person has done this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13781603/keeping-distance-between-panels-the-same

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Anchor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx) property of controls, and can set it even from `Property Window` of VisualStudio in design time.

For more: [How to: Anchor Controls on Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8y52cxte%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

another option, that by the way can be used in conjuction with Anchor is use of 
[TableLayoutPanel](http://www.dotnetperls.com/tablelayoutpanel)